# Custom fields are not pre-populating on profiles added to events, membership, contributions, etc

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, profile, registration

I have some custom contact fields that are not pre-populating the fields on event registrations, memberships, contribution pages, etc. Other fields in the profile pre-populate. When I use the profile in edit mode, the custom fields pre-populate as usual.

This is a fairly new thing, a few months ago, this was not an issue.

Latest Civi/WP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try applying patch from below PR

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16991

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16981

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you - that did it - will that be included in an upcoming release?

Comment: yes 5.25 may be