# Why are custom field's multiple choice options all unchecked on contribution page?

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, custom-fields, multiple-choice

Today I installed 5.25.0 (running with Drupal 7.69). I have a profile that includes a couple of custom fields that are multiple-choice (e.g. professional interests - check all the apply). The choices that are checked appear on the member's profile page and when they edit the profile with those fields directly. So that all looks fine.

Not so much on the contribution page that includes that profile and fields. Every option is unchecked on the contribution page. They used to appear checked on the contribution page, but no more.

Even curiouser...one of the fields is required and the contribution page cannot be submitted unless EVERY option is checked. Normally with this field required, only one option needs to be checked.

So I am wondering if this is a new bug? Anyone else seen this? Suggestions?

Thanks, as always to the community :-)

Comment: since others sometimes get confused excuse me while i clarify some basics. You have some Custom Fields that are then used in a Profile. I assume these fields are set on the Contact entity, and when you say, appears on the Members profile, do you mean the /user page (if drupal). So they are logged in and therefore the profile preloads with their data. so far so good? then with the Contribution page is the person accessing this while logged in, or via a checksum, or any other way. Do their other fields eg Name, DoB etc prefill on the form. and is it just these other custom fields that don't

Comment: if so, are these custom fields standard fields, or multi-record fields, or any thing else that might set them apart from a good old regular custom field.

Comment: Yes, @petednz, that's all accurate. Sorry if I didn't provide enough detail. The issue is when they are logged in and trying to use a contribution form. All the other fields pre-populate correctly. They are standard fields.

Comment: seems this is a duplicate question to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35554/custom-fields-are-not-pre-populating-on-profiles-added-to-events-membership-co/35556#35556 do you agree?

Comment: Probably, except in my case it is only the multiple choice fields and in that case the field types are not specified.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying patch from below PR

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16991

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16981

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: That sounds like it might work. I don't know how to apply a patch though. Will that patch be included in an upcoming CiviCRM update?